# Minimum amount of calories while preventing muscle catabolism?

Tags: daily-caloric-intake, ketogenic-diet

I got a few pounds to shed and I've been considering a lot of different types of diet, but all of them say that no matter how low your calorie intake is, maintaining a large protein intake is crucial - a protein intake around the order of 2g/kg body weight.

I'm also very interested in starting the Keto diet, as I've done it before, but what I've noticed with the Keto diet is a lack of energy, and I am doing a labourer job currently, so I can't have a lack of energy...

Thanks!

Comment: This is a straight nutrition question, and as such, is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a question on setting accurate calorie estimate.
There is a calculator on my page in www.GoodLookingBody.co.uk on page 'FREE'
From there set your protein target at around 2.2g/kg

Fats

You need fat for energy, good skin, and overall health in your body.

If you eat fish few times a week, have a few nuts here and there and use dressing or olive oil in your salads, don’t worry about adding extra fat anywhere else and definitely do not ruin your coffee adding butter to it.

Carbohydrates

They are your physical and mental energy blocks. You need them and they taste good.

You should eat about 3 to 5 g of carbs per 1kg of bodyweight a day. Make sure to eat a mix of fibrous vegetables (asparagus, broccoli, carrots, beans) to feel fuller and have more volume in your food from the calories you get, fruits for taste and vitamins, and starchy carbs like grains and potatoes.

Following the above recommendations and making sure to drink enough water to feel hydrated should cause your fat to vanish into thin air (literally).

As for keto diets this is a great quote
"Therapeutic use of ketogenic diets should not require constraint of most forms of physical labor or recreational activity, with the one caveat that anaerobic (ie, weight lifting or sprint) performance is limited by the low muscle glycogen levels induced by a ketogenic diet, and this would strongly discourage its use under most conditions of competitive athletics." from Phinney SD. Ketogenic diets and physical performance. Nutr Metab (Lond). 2004 Aug 17;1(1):2. in other words, don't bother

References:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23645387
and more